# footer not acting the way I want

Tags: html, css, footer

Massive newbie to html & css,

here is my code for css and html:
http://i.gyazo.com/f97a2815af0a8562f063e6155c2c5ac8.png

the text in question which is not behaving how i want it to (6pt among other things):
http://i.gyazo.com/e056c7b5d6deefd40db67c26e4522f3d.png

Can someone please explain why the footer is not responding to the css?

Comment: Post your relevant HTML and CSS code here, please, and be specific with your problem. "not behaving how you want it to" doesn't help us, because we can't read your mind.

Comment: [Something Is Wrong – Can I Just Post A Link?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: You are missing a `}` at the end of `#shuffle-text` and you adjust color to `footer` but that is not in your HTML, you should put that `color:#F2F2F2;` in the `#footer`. And what is `#class footer`? That is not in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your footer is using a  tag while the css is referencing a  tag with footer { } so you need to change section to footer for it to work:

`<footer id="footer> </footer>`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you're just missing the "p" element, when you write "#footer" in your css you're applying changes to the whole footer and not specifically to your paragraph, so you have to specify the element. (in this case the 'p' element) like this:

```
#footer p{

 //put your code here
}
```

and you should be fine.

Edit.

Also you don't need  the footer element in your css, once you already defined a footer id (#footer).

And finally just a tip, you could make your code more semantic  using the footer element instead a section element with an id called footer.

```
<section id="footer"> 
 <p> </p>

</section>
```

you could simply use:

```
<footer>
 <p> </p>
</footer>
```

and your css instead using:

```
#footer p {} //#footer is the 'id="footer"
```

you could use:

```
footer p{}  //footer is the <footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The element you want to change is the text (p) inside of the footer.
just use

`#footer p {}`

and then all the css code you want to apply to your text.

also you do not need the css element "footer" because none of your html elements are technically footers.
If you want to use the css element "footer" then you can use the html element

`<footer></footer>`

and apply css to it with

`footer p {}`